# Identify this sailing insigina

Tags: sailing, identification

I recently inherited a small sailing boat similar to a Sunfish (roughly 12'x5'). However, I'm pretty sure it's *not* a sunfish, and I'm trying to identify it by the insignia on the sail. Does anyone recognize this symbol and/or what company it belongs to?
[image: Insignia on sail]
[image: Hull]

Comment: Pics of the hull would also be useful.

Comment: Agree, seeing the entire boat might help.  You may also want to try a dedicated sailing forum; a cursory search of about 600+ sailboat logos didn't turn up any matches.

Comment: I can post pictures of the hull itself later, but unfortunately it's entirely devoid of markings. The sail is the only thing that has any defining features. Again, it's very similar to a sunfish; I don't have one in my possession to compare it against, but from my memory, it's maybe a little shallower and thinner than a sunfish.

Comment: How old, and is it from the US or a different country?  If there is a Hull Identification Number, it may be tracked that way: http://www.hinsearchplus.com/hs_userguide.aspx

Comment: I believe it is from the US. It could be over 30 years old; no one really knows much about it in my family, since no one who bought it is still alive! It's been a part of my family cabin's history for at least 30 years. And like I said, the hull is entirely devoid of markings.

Comment: It's quite likely that there's a hand-scratched HIN somewhere on the interior of the boat.  All three of the sailboats I've owned had two HIN areas, one visible on the outside, and another tucked away somewhere on the interior of the boat that you had to know where to look to find.  I searched through a few hundred sail logos as well with no luck.  It's possible that the sail isn't original, and the logo is from a sail loft, not the boat manufacturer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reddit helped me out! It's a Sears Jet wind!